# Dynamically generate factory attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, testing, factory-bot

I want to do following:

```
classes = ["WelcomeMailing", "NoticeMailing", "FeedbackMailing"] #......

FactoryGirl.define do
  classes.each do |tclass|

    cl_attributes = ["body", "subject", "description", "title"]

    # this registers dynamically sequences, which i can use later (this works already!)
    define_sequences(cl_attributes.map{|a| tclass.underscore + "_" + a})

    factory tclass.underscore.to_sym do
      cl_attributes.each do |aattr|
        # here i want to generate the attributes of the factory class dynamically..

        aattr { generate (tclass.underscore + "_" + aattr).to_sym }
        # but it doesnt work
        # => pry(main)> FactoryGirl.create(:custom_mailing_draft)
        # FactoryGirl::AttributeDefinitionError: Attribute already defined: aattr

        # or
        eval(aattr) { generate (tclass.underscore + "_" + aattr).to_sym }            # also not with
        # =>factory_girl/definition_proxy.rb:36:in `add_attribute': Both value and block given (FactoryGirl::AttributeDefinitionError)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

At the end i want to dynamically create the factories (since they nearly are all the same structure (inherited classes)). But like you see in the code, the setting of the attributes doesn't work.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by myself with:

```
  classes.each do |tclass|
    FactoryGirl.define do
      define_sequences(attributes.map{|a| tclass.underscore + "_" + a})

      clstr = "factory :#{tclass.underscore} do;"
      attributes.each do |aattr|
        clstr += "#{aattr} { generate :#{(tclass.underscore + "_" + aattr).to_sym} };"
      end
      clstr += "end"

      eval(clstr)
    end
  end
```